# Approximation of results

Tags: r, approximation

I'm just learning how to use R. I'm practicing some statistic stuff, as Normal distribution, Poisson, etc.

When I try to calculate probabilities and the answer is a number very close to zero (0), the program shows as result 0, so I can't see the full answer, and I need the full answer. There is always a probability, even a small one!!

My question is: can I  turn off the self-approximation or which code can I use to get a full answer?

Example:

```
1-pbinom(q =10, size = 10,prob = 0.8)
```

Result:

```
0
```

Answer (score 3):

The `pbinom` function gives the cumulative density function. That i the probability that a value is less than or equal to a particular value. So with a discrete distribution like the binomial distribution with 10 draws

```
pbinom(10, 10, .8)
# [1] 1
```

tells you that there is a 100% change you will observe 10 or fewer successes.

Perhaps you're thinking of the probability density function (or probability mass function since this is a discrete distribution) `dbinom`

```
dbinom(10, 10, .8)
# [1] 0.1073742
```

means that there is a roughly 11% chance that all your draws will be successes. It's also true that

```
sum(dbinom(0:10, 10, .8))
# [1] 1
```

that the sum of the probabilities of getting 0 through is exactly 1.

So with these cases you are getting the exact answer. R does round values in the console according to the `options(digits=)` setting, but that's not what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

`pbinom` is the distribution function for the binomial distribution, which is discrete and can thus be exactly 1 (as in your example). You might have been thinking of *continuous* distributions like the normal or gamma distributions. In this case, rounding can cause your results to be truncated, for example

```
> 1 - pnorm(10, 0, 1)
[1] 0
```

However, the `p[dist]` functions have an argument `lower.tail=FALSE` designed to address this problem:

```
> pnorm(10, 0, 1, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 7.619853e-24
```